# How prove that $\frac{1}{ 2 π i}\int_{ |z|=R} z^{ n−1} |f(z)|^ 2 dz = a_0 \bar{a_n} R^{ 2 n} $.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = a_0 + a_1z + · · · + a_n z^n$ polynomial of degree $n ≥ 0$. Show that

$$\dfrac{1}{
2 π i} \displaystyle\int_{
|z|=R}
z^{
n−1}
|f(z)|^2
dz = a_0 \bar{a_n} R^{
2 n}
$$

Already tried to use the integral formula of cauchy, induction on $n$, but I can not appear with $\bar{a_n}$ and $R^{
2 n}$. Someone can help.

Comment: No `\displaystyle` and no `dfrac` in titles, thanks (and there are rarely useful elsewhere either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be $ |f(z)|^2 $. Then one can calculate:

$$ \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{|z|=r} z^{n-1} \cdot |f(z)|^2 dz = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} R^n e^{int} i (\sum_{k=0}^n R^k a_ke^{ikt}) (\sum_{j=0}^n R^j \overline{a_j}e^{-ijt})dt \\ = \sum_{k,j=0}^n R^{n+k+j}a_k\overline{a_j} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{i(n+k-j-1)}e^{it}idt = \sum_{k,j=0}^n R^{n+k+j}a_k\overline{a_j} \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{|z|=1} z^{n+k-j-1} dz $$

Then by Cauchy's Integral Theorem $$ \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{|z|=1} z^{n+k-j-1} dz  = \delta_{n (j-k)}$$ where $ \delta_{n (j-k)} $ denotes the Kronecker Delta. This implies:

$$ \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{|z|=r} z^{n-1} \cdot |f(z)|^2 dz = R^{2n} a_0 \overline{a_n} $$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I missed some constants the first time. But they are added now.

Comment: I could not understand the ending, why is the kronecker delta about $n,( j-k)$? Alias, why is the integral exactly this kronecker delta?

Comment: I can understand that when $n = j-k$ the integral is $1$. But how to see the case where $n$ is different from $j-k$? And the final conclusion, as we arrived at the result, did not understand the step.

Comment: If $ n = j - k $ the integrand becomes $ \frac{1}{z-0} $, hence the expression is the indication function of zero with respect to the curve $ \gamma (t) = e^{i \cdot t} $ where t ranges from $ 0 $ to $ 2 \pi $. If the above equality doesn't hold one has the identity $ \frac{d}{dz} \frac{ z^{n+k-j} } {n+k-j} = z^{n+k-j-1} $. Therefore the integral of $ z^{n+k-j-1} $ over any closed curve vanishes.

Comment: I got it. Thank you. Just the end I still do not get it right. What did you do? added all the plots where the kronecker delta is 1. But do multiple terms appear in this correct sum? Because there is only left $R^{2n}a_0\bar{a_n}$? For example, what happens with $R^{2n}a_1\bar{a_{n-1}}$

Comment: If $ k > 0 $ and $ 0 \le j \le n $ it follows $ j - k < j \le n $. So $ n = j-k$ in the sum if and only if $ j = n $ and $ k = 0 $.

Comment: Great! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I conjecture that the strange exponent $1$ should be replaced by a $2$. This means that we are told to compute the quantity
$$Q:={1\over 2\pi i}\int_{\partial D_R}z^{n-1} \bigl|f(z)\bigr|^2\>dz\ .$$
As a **hint** note that on $\partial D_R$ one has $\bar z={R^2\over z}$ and therefore
$$\bigl|f(z)\bigr|^2=f(z)\overline{f(z)}=f(z)\>\bar f\!\!\left({R^2\over z}\right)\ ,$$
whereby the function $\bar f$ is defined by
$$\bar f(z):=\sum_{k=0}^n \overline{a_k}\,z^k\ .$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a comment, in consideration of the other (I think more useful) two answers.

If the stated equality were correct, one would have that, for $R\not=0$, 
$$ {1\over 2 \pi i R^{2n} }\int_{|z| = R} z^{n-1} | f(z)| \,dz ={1\over 2 \pi}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i n\theta} \left| f(R e^{i\theta})\over R^n\right| \, d\theta = a_0\overline a_n.$$

In particular, the quantities would not depend on $R$. But (in the second integral), by taking the limit as $R$ tends to infinity, one gets (interchange of limit and integral justified by dominated convergence, say)that 
$$ \lim_{R\to \infty}{1\over 2 \pi }\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i n\theta} \left| f(R e^{i\theta})\over R^n\right| \, d\theta  = {1\over2 \pi}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i n\theta} |a_n | \, d\theta = 0,$$
for $n\ge 1$. So, assuming the original equality were correct, $a_0\overline a_n = 0$.

Comment: thank you very much for the comment!