# Strange complex analysis proof

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked this question :

Let $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+...+a_nz^n$ be a complex polynomial with complex coefficients. Prove that :

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\limits_{|z|=r}z^{n-1}|f(z)|^2\mathrm{dz}=a_0a_n^*r^{2n}$$

I have tried pretty much everything and I am still lost. I am pretty sure that Cauchy's Theorem gets the job done but I didn't have any luck yet.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2919038/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/655451/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2545726/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Cpi%20i%7D%5Coint%5Climits_%7B%7Cz%7C%3Dr%7Dz%5E%7Bn-1%7D%7Cf(z)%7C%5E2%5Cmathrm%7Bdz%7D%3Da_0a_n%5E*r%5E%7B2n%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: @MartinR Thank you so much!

Comment: Why would Cauchy's Theorem apply here?